# Textjoin or Concatenate for this case?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

hope you have a good day/evening.

Due to I always seems to use importrange function to import multiple sheets. I want to have a quicker way to replace the date (highlighted in red as per the screenshot) with the date referenced in Col A. This is my Google Sheet under the tab name "TextJoin"   [Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=865986079)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
=importrange("_____","'" & text(A2,"M/d/yy") &"'!A2:C")
```

Comment: Hi Mike. Thanks for taking time to answer my questions. Actually my intention is not to pull the data. As i often have to import multiple sheets from one trix, i need to use hardcoded formula such as below, so i just want to have a textjoin/subtitiue formula to replace the date by referencing to ColA. If you dont mind, you can draft in the sheets? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IzDAwti4xnXVgJNfW2q1mrsha01yBkK_skTE_Xgb-uA/edit#gid=865986079

=QUERY(
  {
    IMPORTRANGE("13DWtP4L7swqBgK6BGLeA-o_FfyD-D8-Ru30cOPf0I10", "'4/11/22'!A2:C") and SO ON

Comment: you may apply `=substitute(B1,regexextract(B1,"\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}"),text(A1,"M/dd/yy"))` but this can't be done with a formula in B1 - the only way will be by script - or to use the above solution.

Answer (score 3):

try:

```
=INDEX({""; "={"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, 
 "IMPORTRANGE(""13DWtP4L7swqBgK6BGLeA-o_FfyD-D8-Ru30cOPf0I10"", """&
 FILTER(TO_TEXT(A2:A)&"!A2:C"")", A2:A<>""))&"}"})
```

[image]

but you may need to wrap it into query and remove empty rows perhaps like:

```
=INDEX({""; "=QUERY({"&TEXTJOIN("; ", 1, 
 "IMPORTRANGE(""13DWtP4L7swqBgK6BGLeA-o_FfyD-D8-Ru30cOPf0I10"", """&
 FILTER(TO_TEXT(A2:A)&"!A2:C"")", A2:A<>""))&"}, ""where Col1 is not null"", )"})
```

[image]